# batch file setting system time with GPS

Tags: batch-file, time, gps

My GPS device sends on COM port the NMEA infos. 
I want to extract the time info and set the system time.

In a batch I wrote:

```
type COM2 | find "GPRMC"
```

brings me the required info - but continously. 
Example (first 3 lines):

```
$GPRMC,100211.279,V,4816.1496,N,01623.0965,E,0.00,0.00,280316,,,N*7A
$GPRMC,100212.279,V,4816.1496,N,01623.0965,E,0.00,0.00,280316,,,N*79
$GPRMC,100213.279,V,4816.1496,N,01623.0965,E,0.00,0.00,280316,,,N*78
```

So the next batch command is never executed, because the GPS device is sending as long as it's on.

I want to extract the second field, as in example, it is 100211 and this is 10:02:11 UTC time.

greetings

Comment: Is `copy COM2: CON:` continuous stream as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=,." %%a in ('type COM2 ^| find "GPRMC"') do (
    set "comTime=%%a"
    goto :break
)
:break
set "comTime=%comTime:~0,2%:%comTime:~2,2%:%comTime:~4,2%
echo %comTime%
pause
```

This sets the time of the first line in the file to the variable comTime in the format hh:mm:ss

NOTE

This removes the .279 part of the time, to keep that part change `delims=,.` to `delims=,`

Comment: Thanks Denis, since the GPS device sends continuously, your 'for loop' hangs. It never comes to the break. ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Next code snippet would take line(s) from an endless command output.

- Avoid `|` pipe to `find` or `findstr` ([read more, see *Pipes and CMD.exe* paragraph](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)).
- Think about delay(s) caused by …

  - … involved `timeout` commands,
  - … handling temporary file and
  - … process handling (`cmd`, `taskkill`, `for`).

Tested using endless `ping localhost -4 -t`:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "mycommand=type COM2"
set "mytestval=$GPRMC"
rem next two lines are merely for my tests: remove them both  
set "mycommand=ping localhost -4 -t"
set "mytestval=Reply"
start "bubu36260096" cmd /C ^>"%temp%\aux36260096.txt" %mycommand%
>NUL timeout /T 3 /NOBREAK
>NUL taskkill /T /F /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq bubu36260096"
>NUL timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK
rem                   v--- skip as many lines as you need 
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1,2 delims=, " %%a in ("%temp%\aux36260096.txt") do (
    rem                                    ^--- remove this blank space in above line
    if "%%a"=="%mytestval%" ( 
        set "comTime=%%b"
        goto :break
    )
)
:break
rem next line for debugging purposes only
type "%temp%\aux36260096.txt"
rem set "comTime=%comTime:~0,2%:%comTime:~2,2%:%comTime:~4,2%
echo comTime ... "%comTime%"
pause
```